# Keyboard Hotkey/Macro Software

Tags: keyboard, macros, autohotkey

Im looking for a simple easy-to-use software, that can do the following for me:

When I hold down spacebar, it actually taps it (click down, release, click down, release... etc.) And then stops when I let go.

I've read about AutoHotKey, but I dont really know how to code, and I think that is what you need to in that program.

So I thought I would ask here.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, questions which ask for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly and attract subjective answers. For advice on how to ask a question which may require recommending software, see [this Meta Super User post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/).

Comment: If you ask about the **task** instead of the software, people will be more interested. The task itself is definitely a reasonable request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autohotkey is exactly what you need here. It's really easy - all key-mappings are stored in a script file that you can edit with Notepad (etc.).

To do what you mentioned, pop this into your script file, save, and run it:

```
if (switch = 1) {
switch = 0
send, {Space down}
}
else {
switch = 1
send, {Space up}
}
return
```

**EDIT: Better answer:**

`$Space::

while GetKeyState("space", "P")
{
send {space}
            ; you could have a sleep XXXX statement here
}
return`

Note that this makes it extremely difficult to type single spaces. Adding something like `sleep 25` (adjust number depending on your typing speed) may be helpful if you want to leave the script running all the time.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. So I tried say 'Edit Script' and paste yours in and Save it. Then I say Reload Script right? And then gives me this message: Error at line 1. Line Text:{ Error: The left most character above is illegal in an expression. The script was not reloaded; the old version will remain in effect.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please check out the edited answer. My fault on the previous one.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Could you take it further and stop the script when if you hold down space and you push CTRL the script stops/ends spamming spacebar?